# What is the correct syntax for using 'docker compose' when writing a script?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, debian, gnome

attempting to run

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker compose exec -T ...
```

in order to backup a database file

however when referencing documents I see that docker-compose is typically what was there for v1

for v2 what syntax do I have to use so I don't get `sudo: /usr/local/bin/docker: command not found`

I would like to use the proper v2 version but I don't know how to execute docker compose exec with correct syntax and online documentation is not clear as to why this issue exists or what I should be doing to fix it.

Comment: On my system, docker is located at `/usr/bin/docker`. `sudo /usr/bin/docker compose --help` works and `sudo /usr/local/bin/docker compose --help` fails with `sudo: /usr/local/bin/docker: command not found`. Can you verify the location of your docker install?

Comment: docker is installed in /usr/bin/docker

ah that would be it thank you

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help!

Comment: For a database backup?  Delete all of this, and just run _e.g._ `pgdump` the same way you would without Docker, connecting to a published port of the container.  You don't need `docker` or root permissions to do this.

Comment: @DavidMaze depending on your setup, it may actually be easier to run pgdump from within the docker container that contains the database since that container has the tools like pgdump already installed and you don't need to publish a port outside of the docker network which you may never need to do. I think the approach you suggest is really nice in certain situations, but I don't think it's absolute. I think it depends on what you are already doing with your credentials, tools, and connections.

Comment: Also, for the person who left a -1, could you explain why so that we may improve our questions and answers in the future? This question is a question of syntax, not database backup techniques. Perhaps this question and or answer could be improved to better represent this for future readers?

Answer (score -1):

Just bringing my comment out here as an answer for future readers.

On my system, docker is installed at the location `/usr/bin/docker`.

The following command works for me

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker compose --help
```

and this command

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker compose --help
```

produces the error `sudo: /usr/local/bin/docker: command not found`.

Verifying the location of your docker install may help solve this issue.

Since my `$PATH` includes both `bin` locations, I used

```
which docker
```

to find my install location.

---

An additional note:

If your install location is in your `$PATH` (check with `echo $PATH`), you can use the docker command directly in your shell or scripts.

I usually use a shorter

```
sudo docker compose --help
```

which locates the executable for me.